# Lunar Lobster Wayland crashes

Tags: wayland, 23.04

I recently upgraded to Lunar Lobster from Kinetic Kudu on a desktop system (HP Victus - AMD Ryzen 7 5700G - Radeon RX 6600XT).  Most things are the same or better except Wayland crashes upon suspend/resume or display blank/unlock multiple times a day vs never before, putting me back to a login screen and starting a new session.

I'm unsure offhand how to debug or report as the most annoying aspect of this is that there are no error messages to give me a starting point and Ubuntu itself seems unaware of the problem (i.e., I'm never prompted that there was a "system program problem detected").

I scrolled through journalctl output and the most relevant bits are below (e.g., `org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV`):

```
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus gsd-media-keys[147122]: Unable to get default source
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus ntpd[153912]: DNS: dns_probe: 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org, cast_flags:8, flags:101
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus ntpd[153912]: DNS: dns_check: processing 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org, 8, 101
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus ntpd[153912]: DNS: dns_check: DNS error: -3, Temporary failure in name resolution
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus ntpd[153912]: DNS: dns_take_status: 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org=>temp, 3
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus gnome-shell[148217]: (EE) failed to read Wayland events: Connection reset by peer
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus xdg-desktop-por[147400]: Error reading events from display: Broken pipe
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus gnome-terminal-[147984]: Error reading events from display: Broken pipe
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus x-terminal-emulator[147978]: # Error reading events from display: Broken pipe
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus evolution-alarm[147201]: Error reading events from display: Broken pipe
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus gsd-wacom[147156]: Error reading events from display: Broken pipe
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus gsd-power[147126]: Error reading events from display: Broken pipe
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus gsd-media-keys[147122]: Error reading events from display: Broken pipe
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus gsd-color[147111]: Error reading events from display: Broken pipe
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus gsd-keyboard[147120]: Error reading events from display: Broken pipe
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus update-notifier[148103]: Error reading events from display: Broken pipe
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus systemd[146671]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus snapd-desktop-i[147472]: Error reading events from display: Broken pipe
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus xdg-desktop-por[147518]: Error reading events from display: Broken pipe
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus polkitd(authority=local)[1809]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:51 (system bus name :1.869, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus gsd-xsettings[148234]: Failed to get animations-enabled state: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus systemd[146671]: org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus systemd[146671]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus systemd[146671]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus systemd[146671]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 27 06:52:53 HP-Victus systemd[146671]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 27 06:52:54 HP-Victus systemd[146671]: xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 27 06:52:54 HP-Victus systemd[146671]: xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 27 06:52:54 HP-Victus systemd[146671]: xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 27 06:52:54 HP-Victus systemd[146671]: xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 27 06:52:54 HP-Victus systemd[146671]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 27 06:52:54 HP-Victus systemd[146671]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 27 06:52:54 HP-Victus systemd[146671]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Consumed 2.765s CPU time.
```

And trying to find a core led me to:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E
$ ls -l /var/crash
total 51148
-rw-r----- 1 mjf      whoopsie 52366746 Apr 26 16:11 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 mjf      whoopsie        0 Apr 26 16:11 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.upload
-rw------- 1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Apr 26 16:11 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.uploaded
```

So it caught one and blamed gnome-shell but never prompted me to send a report, and there have been at least 2 crashes since that timestamp.

Comment: This morning's crash also produced a dump but no prompt to submit it.  Anyone know a way to force it to submit a report?

Comment: I have not debugged my problem, but for Lunar Lobster, as well as for Jammy Jellyfish, I have given up using Wayland and I use Xorg, because of continuous crashes of the UI, being redirected to lightdm session login. This is a pity given that Wayland is the default display server now in Ubuntu. I was wondering if having old directories in my home matters because I have my home migrated for about 10 years...

Comment: Fwiw I did try to do a fresh install of `23.04` but the [installer segfaults](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1466923/lunar-lobster-wont-install-from-usb-python-segfault).

Answer (score 0):

The bug is being tracked [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/2012230).

Let's hope for a quick fix!

Update: It has been fixed !